# Gatsby StaticQuery causes "Loading (StaticQuery) to render on page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

So I have a Gatsby blog site which is using a Seo component. The code is basically taken from the Gatsby [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/add-seo-component/) directly with no real changes from me. At one point I was using `useStaticQuery` which resulted in a hard error (used to work fine, then stopped working when I updated gatsby). Now when I run my site, I get a message rendered at the top of the page "Loading (StaticQuery)" which is the weirdest thing ever to just plop onto someone's site. From what I can see, the data never seems to properly load within the HTML Head.

The following code is what I'm using for my Seo component which I'm then importing into each of my pages.

using     `"gatsby": "^3.7.1",`

```
import React from "react"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const Seo = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query SEO {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              title
              description
              titleTemplate
              author
              url
              twitterUsername
              image
              social {
                name
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => {
          const {
            defaultTitle,
            titleTemplate,
            defaultDescription,
            siteUrl,
            defaultImage,
            twitterUsername,
          } = data.site.siteMetadata

          const seo = {
            title: title || defaultTitle,
            description: description || defaultDescription,
            image: `${siteUrl}${image || defaultImage}`,
            url: `${siteUrl}${pathname}`,
          }
          return (
            <Helmet title={seo.title} titleTemplate={titleTemplate}>
              <meta name="description" content={seo.description} />
              <meta name="image" content={seo.image} />

              {seo.url && <meta property="og:url" content={seo.url} />}

              {(article ? true : null) && (
                <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
              )}

              {seo.title && <meta property="og:title" content={seo.title} />}

              {seo.description && (
                <meta property="og:description" content={seo.description} />
              )}

              {seo.image && <meta property="og:image" content={seo.image} />}

              <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />

              {twitterUsername && (
                <meta name="twitter:creator" content={twitterUsername} />
              )}

              {seo.title && <meta name="twitter:title" content={seo.title} />}

              {seo.description && (
                <meta name="twitter:description" content={seo.description} />
              )}

              {seo.image && <meta name="twitter:image" content={seo.image} />}
            </Helmet>
          )
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default Seo
```

[image]

Including Gatsby config file

```
module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Carlos Lantigua",
    titleTemplate: "Random Tech Stuff",
    author: "Carlos Lantigua",
    url: "https://www.thebrowndev.com",
    twitterUsername: "CodeLantigua",
    image: `/src/images/me.jpg`,
    description:
      "This site will be used to dump all of my blogs and projects. A place to keep track of my progression and learnings throughout my time as a Software Developer.",
    social: [
      {
        name: "LinkedIn",
        url: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/carlos-lantigua/",
      },
      {
        name: "Github",
        url: "https://www.github.com/clantigua2",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-G-XXXXXXX", // Google Analytics / GA
        ],
        pluginConfig: {
          head: true,
          // respectDNT: true,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-s3`,
      options: {
        bucketName: "carlos-lantigua-blog-site",
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "www.thebrowndev.com",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `src`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          `gatsby-remark-social-cards`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
          },
          `gatsby-remark-lazy-load`,
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
            options: {
              classPrefix: "language-",
              inlineCodeMarker: null,
              aliases: {
                sh: "bash",
              },
              showLineNumbers: true,
              noInlineHighlight: true,
              languageExtensions: [
                {
                  language: "superscript",
                  extend: "javascript",
                  definition: {
                    superscript_types: /(SuperType)/,
                  },
                  insertBefore: {
                    function: {
                      superscript_keywords: /(superif|superelse)/,
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              prompt: {
                user: "root",
                host: "localhost",
                global: false,
              },
              escapeEntities: {},
            },
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 865,
              loading: "lazy",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-typography",
      options: {
        pathToConfigModule: `${__dirname}/src/utils/typography`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-transition-link`,
      options: {},
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-disqus`,
      options: {
        shortname: `clantigua`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-polyfill-io`,
      options: {
        features: [`Array.prototype.map`, "crypto"],
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `thebrowndev.com`,
        short_name: `browndev`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#f7f0eb`,
        theme_color: `#a2466c`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `src/images/Carlos-Lantigua-midcrop-small.jpg`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you share the gatsby doc URL with me? Let me check...
And also share the gatsby-config.js file with me.

Comment: @OscarCardosoGarcia sure thing, added to the OP

Comment: Can you share the console.log result with me, please?

Comment: So while getting ready to run that console log I noticed that my Seo was named in all caps as `SEO.js`. I changed it to `Seo.js` and that resolved the issue for some strange reason. The data is properly being applied to the header as well. Thanks for trying to help me resolve this one, it's been bugging me for two days 

Comment: Good to hear. :)